# Xcodes UI Testing showing out of date page info

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, xcode-ui-testing

Currently have the following method:

```
func waitForOptionalElement(explicitElement: XCUIElement, timeout: Int) {
    var waitedDuration = 0
    while waitedDuration < timeout {
        if explicitElement.exists {
            break
        }
        waitedDuration++
        sleep(1)
    }
}
```

This method is aimed at waiting until an object appears on the screen. The trouble I have is that if `explicityElement` is not present on the screen when the method is called, then `explicitElement.exists` always returns a `false` (even when the object appears). It is like the `explicitElement` is not refreshed when the page changes, but keeps checking the original view rather than any updated view.

If I call the `explicitElement` in full e.g. 
`XCUIApplication().staticTexts["Error message"].exists` 
then that will come back `true`. It's as if you need to call `XCUIApplication()...` to get an updated view of the current page?

Anyone know any clever ways round this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be more appropriate to use [expectationForPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xctestcase/1500569-expectationforpredicate?language=objc).

```
expectationForPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "exists == true"), evaluatedWithObject: XCUIApplication().staticTexts["Error message"], handler: nil)
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(15.0, handler: nil)
```

Comment: The view hierarchy doesn't update every time the while loop executes. Using waitForExpectationsWithTimeout ensures the view hierarchy that is checked against for the assertions is refreshed.

Comment: Indeed, UI Test framework heavily caches the view hierarchy.

Comment: Really annoys me the way it heavily caches the view hierachy. So easy to get caught out.